# How to exit the app when OutOfMemoryError comes by showing JOption message?

Tags: java

If OutOfMemoryError comes up , then will not able to execute further process.So, How to free the memory and show JOption message with OutOfMemoryError in Java, when OutOfMemoryError comes up ?

Comment: If you get an `OutOfMemoryError` your JVM is dead in the water. There's nothing useful you can do. Any kind of `Error` is essentially unrecoverable and the JVM will terminate immediately whether you want it to or not.

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` inherits from [`java.lang.Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) which its documentation says:

> An `Error` is a subclass of `Throwable` that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application **should not try to catch**. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.

When an `Error` is thrown it indicates that there might be something terribly wrong with your JVM and it might not be in a recoverable state. So catching it is not a good practice.

Comment: ThankYou friend but how the user get alert message ?

Comment: @Muthuganesh Since `JOption` needs fresh memory blocks from heap and your JVM is already dead, you cannot use that JVM to alert user this way. A separate process/JVM might be needed to watch return code of the this process/JVM and alert user.

Comment: OK Friend. Is there any way to free memory from heap space by programmattically and show the alert message with same JVM ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not safe to recover from an OOME, and that probably includes attempting to notify the user via a GUI dialog box.

The recommended approach is to either allow the JVM to crash (writing a stacktrace to standard output / standard error) OR catch the OOME, log it and call `System.exit(...)`.

The problem with attempting to recover by freeing memory, etc is that the "out of memory" may have caused damage on the current thread or other threads that may lead to your application locking up ... or doing damage to critical files / databases / whatever that.  (The operative word is "may" ...)